# Can I change the content of a dataframe inside a dict, without losing the reference of that dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes and dictionary:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my-data.csv')
new_df = pd.read_csv('new-data.csv')

my_dfs = {'first': df }
```

If I do this:

```
my_dfs['first'] = new_df.copy()
```

the `new_df` is not assigned to `df`. It replaces it.

I want to be able to do `print(df)` and that would print the content of `new_df`.

So basically I want to preserve the ID instance of `df` and just change its content

Comment: What do you mean by 'assign without replacing'? Can you add some input example / expected output?

Comment: basically I want the df's instance ID to remain the same. Not be replaced by new_df's instance ID. 
So that my_dfs['first'] still points to 'df', but 'df' would be identical to 'new_df'

Comment: Do you mean like `my_dfs['first'][:] = new_df.copy()`? You're trying to overwrite the `df` variable? Not change which object is stored in the dictionary?

Comment: I just want to change the *content* of df, without changing the reference of df. So that I can still call 'df' after that code and still get the modified 'df'

Comment: That's correct. I don't want to change the object that is in the dictionary

Comment: Why do you want this? This sounds like an XY problem.  What is your ultimate goal? Does `new_df` and `df` have the same shape and/or columns and index?

Comment: This works for me; `my_dfs = {'first': df}
for key in my_dfs:
    key= new_df.copy()
key`  You have to iterate the dictionary I think

Comment: I want to do this because I want 'df' to be accessed from outside that function, regardless of whether it was modified or not

Comment: I don't understand why `my_dfs['first'][:] = new_df.copy()` doesn't do what you expect. It seems that overwriting the values in the DataFrame referenced at `my_dfs['first'` and `df` is what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the dictionary;

```
my_dfs = {'first': df}
for key in my_dfs:
    key= new_df.copy()
print(key)
print(my_dfs['first'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, my ultimate goal is to do `print(df)` and get the same result

Comment: What do you exactly mean, does that alter the results. Did we need to include `key= new_df.copy(deep=True)`?